# Accessing XML data that has been zipped

Tags: xml, db2, zip

Is it possible to use the db2 table stuff to make a query on a column IF the column contains zipped XML?

If so, what would a trivial example be?

That is, given a table:

```
| id | zipped_content
| 0  | some zipped content here that was once xml
```

where the zipped content might look like:

```
<animals>
    <cat>
        <name>fluffy</name>
        <age>12</age>
    <cat>  
    <dog>
        <name>snoopy</name>
        <age>32</age>
    <dog>
</animals>
```

Can I run a query that will, for a given id pull out certain data from the zipped_content?

that is, get the name and age of each animal only? that's a little tricky with the xml db2 stuff - but presumably you get my drift. Can i unzip and then use the tables stuff, or is that impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You could, but the performance would absolutely kill your applications. You can't really use indexes on the structure of your compressed XML. Also, the uncompressing would require temporary memory space, and you would need to think about caching as well.

Why are you zipping the XML? To be honest I can think of very few valid reasons for that.

If for transporting over some REST API or similar, just make sure your web servers will use deflate or gzip, and you will reach compression without losing too much performance.

If you wish to save space, just ask the [DB2 to compress the table](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0605ahuja/) for you.

If for some other weird requirements, store both the zipped and unzipped version. Use triggers to update the other when the other gets changed.

IF you really want to go over and use compressed fields you should probably do it with a combination of [stored procedures](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idm/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.datatools.routines.tutorial.doc/topics/routines_introduction.html) and SQL queries. You might want to develop a compression/decompression procedure and combine it with using temporary tables, or develop a procedure to handle your queries completely - or a combination of both. Yes, C/C++/Java development is required.